# Network Analyst breaking ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I have the following Model which is working fine. It's iterating in all features of my cities center layers and adding it as a facily Location. I want to run one at a time. However when it doesn't attend any demand point, because the cutoff I set it breaks my model, instead of running the next city center.

Do you know how to run through all my cities centers without breaking my model if it doesn`t attend any demand point?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Solve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/solve.htm) tool has a 'Terminate on solve error' parameter that is checked by default and will stop the script if you encounter an error. Unchecking it will let the script go on if the current analysis didn't return results or went wrong for some reason.